# Celery does not revoke tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I plan tasks like this - `task_id = function_with_celery_decorator.delay(args).id` and then trying to do:

```
from celery.app.control import Control
celery_control = Control()
celery_control.revoke(task_id_got_from_db)
```

But no result - task will still be done, and there is noting in logs in console of both

```
python manage.py celeryd -l INFO &
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Comment: Maybe the task is already running? Have you tried `revoke(id, terminate=True)`? Or even more brutally `revoke(id, terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')`?

Comment: @welter could it be already running if it's timeout is not ended yet? Anyway, I tried your variand and no luck. but thatks!

Comment: A few months ago I have also tried to revoke some tasks in Celery, used with RabbitMQ. From what I've learned is that Celery does prefetch a few tasks for each process. After it does that it seemed very hard to revoke a task, I don't know why, because the documentation suggests it still should be possible. I hoped that something has changed. You may try changing [this](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-prefetch-multiplier) variable and try to revoke more that one task to see if it is the same issue.

Comment: @welter thanks, so as a conclusion - I added code to revoke transaction in my project, lets hope it work as expected:)

Comment: @welter had same problem here. I will try to fix it and make a pull request. basically to quick solve it, we implemented a "revoked tasks queue" on our database and subclassed from celery Task checking if the current ID is not listed in the database. If it's listed, it removes it from the database and quits instead executing the task code itself.